# Error in calculating H+ activity

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

I'm starting to study thermodynamics of minerals and rocks, so sorry for the basic question. I am trying to work out some exercises of a book and I found this:

> Calculate the activity of $\ce{H+}$ when the activity of $\ce{Sn^4+}$ is $10^{-10}$ for the reaction $\ce{SnO2 + 4H+ <=> Sn^4+ + 2H2O}$. Standard free energies of formations $\Delta$F<sup>o</sup><sub>f</sub> are: SnO<sub>2</sub> = -123.20 kcal; H<sub>2</sub>O = -56.69 kcal; Sn<sup>4+</sup> = 0.65 kcal; H<sup>+</sup> = 0.

I used the following equations:

> *$\Delta$F<sup>o</sup><sub>r</sub> = ($\Sigma$$\Delta$F<sup>o</sup><sub>f,products</sub>) - ($\Sigma$$\Delta$F<sup>o</sup><sub>f,reactants</sub>)*
>
> *$\Delta$F<sup>o</sup><sub>r</sub> = -RTln(K)*, where *R = 0.001987 Kcal/molK* and *T = 298.15K*
>
> *K = $\frac{[Sn^{4+}]}{[H^{+}]^4}$*, given that the activities of SnO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>O are unit.

The result I found was $3.82 \cdot 10^{-5}$, but the book says the result is $10^{-0.40}$. I assume this is a fundamental error, but given it is also a fundamental principle I need to understand it to proceed in my study.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There got to be some constants, right? Also, your answer looks more realistic to me.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just added the standard free energies of formation

Comment: What units are the free energies of formation?  kJ / mol?  kcal / mol?  pettajoules per picomole?  picojoules per exagram?

Comment: We'll also need temperature...

Comment: Your value for $R$, above, should not be negative. It will help you to always use proper units. The Kelvin doesn't get a "degree" sign. Finally, your value for $R$ should include a per mole unit.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \Delta G = \Delta G^\circ + RT \ln{\frac{a_{\ce{Sn^{4+}}}a_{\ce{H2O}}^{\;\;\;\;2}}{a_{\ce{SnO2}}a_{\ce{H+}}^{\;\;4}}} $$

At equilibrium, $\Delta G = 0$.

For $\Delta G^\circ = 2\times(-56.69) + 0.65 - (-123.20 - 4\times0) = +10.47\mathrm{\frac{kcal}{mol}}$

The question says "activity", but in the absence of any other information, let's assume that "activity" is equal to "concentration".  That is, let's assume [activity coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient) are 1.

Thus, we get $$ \Delta G = 0 = +10.47  + RT \ln{\frac{a_{\ce{Sn^{4+}}}\cdot1^2}{1\cdot a_{\ce{H+}}^{\;\;4}}} $$

Thus, we get $$ {\left( \frac{-10.47}{RT}\right)}  = \ln{{10^{-10}} a_{\ce{H+}}^{\;\;-4}} = -4\ln{a_{\ce{H+}}} -10 \ln{10} $$

$$\frac{\frac{-10.47}{RT} + 10 \ln{10}}{-4} = \ln{a_{\ce{H+}}}$$

Comment: I calculated with the parameters given in the problem and your reasoning gave a third result: 0.2623.

I know why my answer and yours are different.
you used *$\Delta$G = $\Delta$Go - RTlnK*, whereas I just used *$\Delta$G0 = - RTlnK*. I guess I am now even more confused. Was I supposed to assume equillibrium (*$\Delta$G = 0*) even if the problem doesn't specify?

Comment: I got 0.262 without assuming $\Delta G = 0$. Perfectly workable with the equations you have above. Unfortunately, this is not the $10^-0.4$ you were looking for...

Comment: Could you reply showing me how you did it without *$\Delta$G = 0*?  Can't get to that using the equations I showed.

Comment: If you use the $\Delta G^\circ = - RT \ln{K}$ equation, then you are assuming that $\Delta G = 0$.  That's how you get that equation.  (It comes from $\Delta G = \Delta G^\circ + RT \ln{K})$.

Comment: Also this discussion made me realize I made a sign error above in my answer.  I'll edit to correct.